# After deletion: outliers near maximum, remaining in R boxplot

Tags: r, outliers

After creating a function in R which should return a vector of outliers substituted with NA's for some data, I got the outlier remaining nearby the maximum:

```
kill_outliers <- function(data, na.rm=TRUE){
  q <- quantile(data, probs=c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm=na.rm)
  killed <- data
  intq <- 1.5 * IQR(data, na.rm=na.rm)
  killed[x < (q[1]-intq)] <- NA
  killed[x > (q[2]+intq)] <- NA
  killed
}
```

After using this function boxplot(killed) shows:

[image: With deleted outliers]

Why there is an outlier? I have tried:

```
killed[x > (q[2] + intq)] <- NA
```

assuming it's the matter of less or equal, however it hasn't changed anything.

`(q[2] + intq) == 216.87` and the last value in sorted dataset after deletion is `216.16`, which should fit.
Additionally, I don't understand why, when I have used 3rd quantile `(q[3] + intq)`, it didn't exclude any outlier at all...

#### EDIT

As machine indicated, the problem is a matter of creating a new dataset with a new IQR. Thus I conclude, that boxplot() creates a new plot estimating IQR for each dataset. Additional question: is there a way to fit the new dataset to the previous plot created by boxplot, so as to fit the values to the former quantiles?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but in case you're changing the data just in order to plot a boxplot without displaying the outliers, you can achieve this more easily by simply using ```boxplot(x,outline=F)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function deletes outliers and thereby, you get a new distribution of your variable with a *new* IQR. With the new IQR other values can be outliers that were not outliers with the IQR of the original variable (and therefore are not killed). Thus, you need to rerun your function again and again as long as there are outliers.

Here is a code that runs as long as there are outliers:

```
kill_outliers <- function(data, na.rm=TRUE){
q <- quantile(data, probs=c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm=na.rm)
  intq <- 1.5*IQR(data, na.rm=na.rm)
intq_low <- q[1]-intq
intq_high <- q[1]+intq

killed <- data
while(any(killed < intq_low, na.rm=TRUE) | any(killed > intq_high, na.rm= TRUE)){ 
  killed[killed<intq_low] <- NA
  killed[killed>intq_high] <- NA

q <- quantile(killed, probs=c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm=na.rm)
  intq <- 1.5*IQR(killed, na.rm=na.rm)
intq_low <- q[1]-intq
intq_high <- q[1]+intq
}
killed
}

boxplot(kill_outliers(rnorm(9999)))
```

Besides, in your function there is an undefined objext `x` that is probably in your environment and causes problems, too.

Comment: However, if I delete outliers repeatedly, it seems as if I changed the data, isn't it? For me too many deletions means too many changes to the data. If I want to stick to the data as precisely as it's possible, is it acceptable to run the first deletion and add a comment to the boxplot, that deleting the outliers has resulted in changing the IQR, but I want to stick to the first IQR?

Comment: @Question That is a new question. My opinion: Of course you change your data which is also the case if we delete outliers once. The most important thing for publication is to precisly report how you transformed your data. I guess it depends on the field you work in how you treat outliers. If my post answer the question as it stands consider marking it as answered since this is how this website works.

Answer (score 0):

@machine is right, removing "outliers" will change the distribution and its parameters.

I want to add, that removing outliers should never be done without serious reasons. The fact that a point exceeds the whiskers in a boxplot is no such reason. A small number of close-by values is completely normal, while a large number of such points may be considered as indicator for a non-normal the distribution. I prefer to avoid the term outlier in such cases and call it differently, e.g. extreme values.

```
set.seed(765)
boxplot(rnorm(100))    # normal distribution
boxplot(rt(100, df=3)) # t distribution with long tails
boxplot(rlnorm(100))   # lognormal, skewed
```

All these examples do not qualify for outlier removal. Another case is, when some points are created by a separate "process" bigger than the usual variance or measurement error.

```
boxplot(c(rnorm(100), 7))
```

Here, an outlier test can be applied, e.g. `outlierTest` from package **car** with Bonferroni correction:

```
library(car)
outlierTest(lm(x ~ 1))
```

It is clear, that such a test must not be applied repeatedly.

Search crossvalidated and you will find several good articles about outlier problems, e.g. [whether to delete cases that are flagged as outliers ...](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15426/whether-to-delete-cases-that-are-flagged-as-outliers-by-statistical-software-whe/50780) or [is it cheating to drop the outliers based on the boxplot ...](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263238/is-it-cheating-to-drop-the-outliers-based-on-the-boxplot-of-mean-absolute-error/263251)

Comment: I agree with you. I tried to answer the question from a Stack Overflow perspective and therefore left out the statistical concerns. Depending on what the OP actually wanted to know this in fact may be more suited for Cross Validated.

Comment: I don't want to repost question which has been answered on CV, as tpetzoldt has cited. However, these answers relate mostly to fitting the regression line. What about the **confidence interval**, which is my aim? Is it still recommended then to save the outliers? (Or my question is too CV for this site?) EDIT: I really appreciate your answers :) They are very helpful

Comment: The general principle is the same. A confidence interval for the mean value is comparable to the intercept of a regression with slope zero, a so-called null model: `lm(y ~ 1)`.